# require is not defined in node command line

Tags: node.js, typescript, require, commonjs

I have a typescript project that was compiling and running perfectly fine but now I get the error
`ReferenceError: require is not defined` whenever I try to run node.

I'm not completely sure this is a Typescript issue because when I run a simple plain js file using `require` I get the same error. I'm a little confused since require should be defined when using `node index.js` isn't it?

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  "include": ["src/"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I had enabled experimental support for ES6 Modules in the `package.json`.

Removing the option: `"type": "module"` from `package.json` solved all my problems.

See here: [ECMAScript modules on Official NODEjs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_modules_ecmascript_modules)